# Are there any references to Formless-Ishvara in scriptures or in Advaitic teachings?

Tags: scripture, advaita, upanishads, brahman

Brahman is essentially Nirguna and Ishwara is Saguna Brahman via Maya.

Whenever I come across the term Ishvara, an image of either Vishnu or Shiva pops up in my mind.

But I've also heard that Ishvara can be Saguna and **Nirakar** and so I'd like to know if there are any scriptural references to this notion? Would OM(or AUM) be a correct example?